# Ubuntu Core 16 GUI?

Tags: ubuntu-core

Is it possible to install graphical interface to Ubuntu Core 16? The reason is for a graphical Qt application with windows/buttons/lists and so on. I use Raspberry Pi3 board with HDMI connected display and USB mouse.

Thanks, Andrei